# C# delegate argument type

Tags: c#, delegates

```
    delegate void Dele(string str);
    delegate void Alli(int num);

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dele dele = Test; // O
            Alli alli = Test; // X          
        }        

        static void Test(object obj) { }
    }
```

`Alli alli = Test; // X`
Why???

Maybe...
`str as object` ( O )
`num as object` ( X )
???

(Sorry, I'm not good at English)
(It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.: OK)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is specified in the C# language specification.

Here:

```
Dele dele = Test;
```

You are doing a [method group conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#method-group-conversions). One of the requirements for a method group conversion to be allowed is that

> The selected method M must be compatible (Delegate compatibility) with the delegate type D, or otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

[Delegate compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/delegates#delegate-compatibility) is specified like this (emphasis mine):

> A method or delegate M is compatible with a delegate type D if all of
>   the following are true:
>
> - D and M have the same number of parameters, and each parameter in D has the same ref or out modifiers as the corresponding parameter in M.
> - **For each value parameter (a parameter with no ref or out modifier), an identity conversion (Identity conversion) or implicit
>     reference conversion (Implicit reference conversions) exists from the
>     parameter type in D to the corresponding parameter type in M.**
> - For each ref or out parameter, the parameter type in D is the same as the parameter type in M.
> - An identity or implicit reference conversion exists from the return type of M to the return type of D.

There *is* an implicit reference conversion from `string` to `object`, because `string` is a subclass of `object`, but there *isn't* an implicit reference conversion from `int` to `object`. `int` is a value type, so the conversion is actually a *boxing conversion*. Therefore, the method group conversion does not work for `Alli` and `Test`.

Comment: Nicely written answer. upvote for your march towards 100k